# Parsing an html file and adding found images to a zip file

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to parse an html for all its img tags, download all the images pointed to by src, and then add those files to a zip file. I would prefer to do all this in memory since I can guarantee there won't be that many images.

Assume the images variable is already populated from parsing the html. What I need help with is getting the images into the zipfile.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO
from urllib2 import urlopen

s = StringIO()
zip_file = ZipFile(s, 'w')
try:
    for image in images:
        internet_image = urlopen(image)
        zip_file.writestr('some-image.jpg', internet_image.fp.read())
        # it is not obvious why I have to use writestr() instead of write()
finally:
    zip_file.close()
```

Comment: use urllib2 / lxml / xpath / google

Comment: To second Brian Agnew's remarks, it looks like you've pretty much got it all sorted. You have to use zip_file.writestr() because you're writing from a buffer of bytes (ie: a byte string) rather than from a file located on the filesystem (which is what zip_file.write() expects to receive).

Comment: Don’t forget stylesheet and images referenced therein...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about how you create the ZIP archive (others here have discussed parsing the URLs), I tested out your code. You are really remarkably close to having a finished product already.

Here's how I would augment what you have to create a Zip archive (in this example, I'm writing the archive to the drive so that I can verify it was properly written).

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo, ZIP_DEFLATED
import zlib
from cStringIO import StringIO
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urlparse import urlparse
from os import path

images = ['http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png', 
          'http://sstatic.net/so/Img/footer-cc-wiki-peak-internet.png']

buf = StringIO()
# By default, zip archives are not compressed... adding ZIP_DEFLATED
# to achieve that. If you don't want that, or don't have zlib on or
# system, delete the compression kwarg
zip_file = ZipFile(buf, mode='w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED)

for image in images:
    internet_image = urlopen(image)
    fname = path.basename(urlparse(image).path) 
    zip_file.writestr(fname, internet_image.read())

zip_file.close()

output = open('images.zip', 'wb')
output.write(buf.getvalue())
output.close()
buf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here, since you appear to have most of it sorted.

Have you investigated [HtmlParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) to actually perform the HTML parsing ? I wouldn't try hand-rolling a parser yourself - it's a major task with numerous edge cases. Don't even think about regexps for anything but the most trivial cases.

For each `<img/>` tag you can use [HttpLib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) to actually get each image. It may be worth getting the images in multiple threads to speed up the compilation of the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to do this would be to use the BeautifulSoup library.

Something along the lines of:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

def getImgSrces(html):
    srcs = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for tag in soup('img'):
        attrs = defaultdict(str)
        for attr in tag.attrs:
            attrs[ attr[0] ] = attr[1]
        attrs = dict(attrs)

        if 'src' in attrs.keys():
            srcs.append( attrs['src'] )

    return srcs
```

That should give you a list of URLs derived from your img tags to loop through.

Comment: Why not just have: `for attr in tag.attrs: if attr[0] == 'src': srcs.append(attr[1])` instead? Why bother with your `attrs` dictionary?

Comment: I just took the example almost verbatim out of a routine I had written where I wanted a dictionary of all attributes, though you could do it that way.

I'm not sure there's much to gain there performance-wise, though.